# SQL SELECT JOIN duplicate output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is the query

```
    SELECT 
        f.id AS main_forum_id,
        f.forumname AS main_forumname,
        m.useraid AS main_forum_moderator_id,
        m.useradn AS main_forum_moderator_dn,
        f2.id AS sub_forum_id,
        f2.forumname AS sub_forumname,
        m2.useraid AS sub_forum_moderator_id,
        m2.useradn AS sub_forum_moderator_dn
    FROM forums f
        LEFT JOIN moderator m ON(m.forumid=f.id)
        LEFT JOIN forums f2 ON(f2.relatedto=f.id)
        LEFT JOIN moderator m2 ON(m2.forumid=f2.id)
    WHERE f.adminid='$userid'
        AND f.relatedto=0
    ORDER BY f.id,f2.id DESC
```

This is the output:
[image]

Any idea how to fix it?
What's wrong with my query?

WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO IS:

**Main forum:**

- Moderator 1
- Moderator 2
- moderator 3...

  **Subforum:**

  - Moderator 1
  - Moderator 2...

  **Subforum:**

  - Moderator 1...

**ANATHER Main forum:**

- Moderator 1..... etc..

Comment: you are missing GROUP BY

Comment: GROUP BY WHAT? there is nothing to group by with...

Comment: @user2124281 There are three different sub forum mods, which one do you want to return?

Answer (score 2):

The data is repeated because you have three separate `sub_forum_moderator_id` and `sub_forum_moderator_dn` values so you have distinct rows for each one.

You have a few options, you can use an aggregate function to return one value for each of those columns or you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine those rows into a single row:

```
SELECT f.id AS main_forum_id,
  f.forumname AS main_forumname,
  m.useraid AS main_forum_moderator_id,
  m.useradn AS main_forum_moderator_dn,
  f2.id AS sub_forum_id,
  f2.forumname AS sub_forumname,
  group_concat(m2.useraid) AS sub_forum_moderator_id,
  group_concat(m2.useradn) AS sub_forum_moderator_dn
FROM forums f
LEFT JOIN moderator m ON(m.forumid=f.id)
LEFT JOIN forums f2 ON(f2.relatedto=f.id)
LEFT JOIN moderator m2 ON(m2.forumid=f2.id)
WHERE f.adminid='$userid'
  AND f.relatedto=0
GROUP BY f.id, f.forumname, m.useraid, m.useradn,
  f2.id, f2.forumname
ORDER BY f.id,f2.id DESC
```

Comment: but im still getting duplicate data, the onl diffrent is the usernames are in array now. also i can't get the subforum_moderator_id

Comment: @user2124281 My suggestion would be to edit your post with your table structures, some sample data for each table and then the desired result.

Comment: i've added "CONVERT(m2.useraid, CHAR(8))" to fix the subforum_moderator_id, but i still getting the red and blue rows, this time each block got into 1 row

Comment: @user2124281 It is difficult without seeing your table structures and some data.

Comment: @user2124281 Unfortunately I don't have access to that.  Can you create a sql fiddle -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/  --with your tables and some data?

Comment: i dont know how, does printscreen will be ok?

Comment: @user2124281 No a screen print will not work. Can you edit your original post with the table DDL and some sample data?

Comment: Maybe `distinct` is needed in these group_concats: `group_concat(DISTINCT m2.useraid)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT(f.id)` or `DISTINCT(forum.id)`, also add `GROUP BY f.id` in your query,
this will eliminate the duplicate results.

Answer (score 0):

```
try : SELECT DISTINCT
```

not sure it works